# How to echo each magit command after each action?

Tags: magit

Although I can use `$` to see the command histories, I'd like to see it immediately each time I performed an action.

E.g. Display `git push -v origin master\:refs/heads/master` after <kbd>P</kbd> <kbd>p</kbd>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no support for that but at least `git push` will be displayed in the mode-line while the pushing is in progress.

Comment: I wish this feature because I want to learn every git command from every magit keystroke I pressed.